# Events page template pagination not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Here's my code the pagination is not working and the archive url that I've created was /resources/industry-event

` <?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'events',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_key'       => 'event_date_start',
'meta_value'     => date('Ymd'),
'meta_compare'   => '>=',
'orderby'        => 'rand',
'order'          => 'ASC',
// 'paged' => $paged
);

```
        $futureposts = new WP_Query($args);

        if ( $futureposts->have_posts() ) : 
        
          while($futureposts->have_posts()) : $futureposts->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">                                    
                                    <div class="img-hover-zoom" style="position: relative;"><a href="<?php the_field('event_url'); ?>">
                                        <img src="<?php the_field('event_logo'); ?>">
                                        <div class="title-inn">
                                        <h3><a href="<?php the_field('event_url'); ?>" style="color: #fff; font-weight: 500;"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="events-content">
                                        <?php the_field('event_description'); ?><a href="<?php the_field('event_url'); ?>">Learn More</a>
                                    </div>                                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="pagination">
                    <?php 
                        echo paginate_links( array(
                            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                            'total'        => $futureposts->max_num_pages,
                            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
                            'show_all'     => false,
                            'prev_next'    => true,
                            'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( '«' ) ),
                            'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( '»' ) ),
                        ) );
                    ?>
                </div>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>`
```

I've tried the code above